# "worse" vs. "less better"

Tags: word-choice, comparatives

What is the right way to convey the meaning that I want to say?

> Your job *is worse than* mine, so I am not going to quit my job.

Is there a better choice to say this? Should I use *less better than* instead?

Comment: 'less better' is not unlike a litotes. 'worse' is better than 'less better'

Comment: But I don't think _less better_ is worse; it's quite novel. And it smacks of political spin control.

Comment: @JohnLawler Awfully magnanimous of you to accept "less better" as having any validity at all. Do you really think it's grammatically reasonable?

Comment: It's a nonce expression, and they don't need to obey all the rules. It doesn't bear strict analysis of course: '80% is better than 40% (of something desirable); 65% is less better.' Sounds ridiculous; we'd rephrase.

Comment: How about, more ungood.

Answer (score 6):

Your alternatives might probably be *worse than* and *not as good as*. I know what you mean by *less better than*, but sadly, that's not a proper phrase.

*Worse than* puts *your job* a rank **below** *my job*, while it puts *my job* itself into the *bad* class.

*Not as good as* also places *your job* a rank **below** *my job*. However, in this case it places *my job* in the *good* class.

Comment: I do agree, but I think "worse" is fairly commonly used when making a comparison to something good.

Comment: @John M. Landsberg _ not when (a) they're both pretty good; (b) you don't want to sound disparaging.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I concede the point.

Comment: According to me, the better choice is - **Your job is not as good as mine, so I am not going to quit my job**.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the only possible meaning of "less better" would be "better by a smaller margin." In other words, if X is a lot better than Z, and Y is *just a little bit* better than Z, then Y would be "less better" than X.

This is a construction for which I find little use.

Furthermore, note that "less better" does *not* mean "not as good." In my example, both X and Y are better than Z, albeit to different degrees. Neither one is worse. Therefore "less better" cannot be a synonym of "worse."

Simple answer: Do not use "less better" at all.

Comment: @Kris Sorry, Kris, I guess my brain is indeed shorting out, because I just don't get what you mean here. Did I write something terribly wrong?

Comment: Not at all. 21 minutes ago, we posted near identical answers.

Comment: @Kris Ah, okay, I see. Mine must have popped in as you were writing, so that neither of us saw the other before posting. But I'm glad to be in sync with you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "less better" would never be appropriate in this context.  "Better" is a comparative.  At least in my opinion, anything which is "less better" needs to be "less better" *than something*.  For example, if you were comparing Person A's job and Person B's job, to Person C's job, then you could write "A's job is less better than B's job [compared to C's job]."

In this case, you *could* use "less good," but that's an unusual formation.  "Worse" however, is a much more common formation, and I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

We can take a different spin on this for the same desired effect.

"Your job is *lacking* when compared to mine."

You can pinky-out and class things up with, "Your job is *wanting* when compared to mine."

We may as well add this to the mix, while we're at it: "Your job is *unsuitable* when compared to mine."